# Converter função for next ASP para PHP

Tags: php, asp

Tenho esta função em ASP e preciso converter para PHP

**DADOS:**

```
cod = "01A" ou cod = "01B" ou cod = "01C"

titulo = "Novidade"
```

**FUNÇÃO:**

```
letra = right(cod,1)
str = array("A","B","C")
for i = lBound(str) to ubound(str)
if (instr(1,letra,str(i),vbtextcompare) <> 0) then
    titulo = titulo & "-" & i+2
end if
next
```

**RESULTADO:**

```
se cod="01A" então titulo = "Novidade-1"

se cod="01B" então titulo = "Novidade-2"

se cod="01C" então titulo = "Novidade-3"
```

Agradeço a todos pela ajuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olha o que eu entendi da pergunta, você quer que a letra corresponda a um index? Se for isso veja se essa solução te atende:

```
 <?php
  $letras = range('A', 'Z');
  $cod = '10F';
  $titulo = "Novidade";

  $letra = substr($cod,-1);
  $index = array_search($letra, $letras)+1;

  print "$titulo-$index\n";
```

Ta certo que eu extrapolei um pouquinho do seu resultado, mas o resultado final seria esse:

```
Novidade-6
```

Comment: quase. O cod é uma variável única. Exemplo: Chegou uma variável $cod='10F'. Então separa a letra F compara e acrescenta -6 no titulo. A função checa só um cod. de cada vez. E o resultado é único: cod=10F terá novidade-6. Obrigado

Comment: kkkkkkkkkkkkk, entendi... mas isso é mais fácil... é a gnt responde mais abrangente, pra contemplar tudo... mas é só retirar do array

Comment: Flavio fiz assim e funcionou: $arr = array($cod); Coloquei a variável única dentro do arr(array). Mas dá para reduzir mais? O meu raciocínio é antigo, Com 70 anos e 50 de linguagens ultrapassadas. Agora que estou convertendo asp em php. Conto com a compreensão dos colegas. Obrigado

Comment: Flávio e rray, agradeço imensamente as rápidas respostas. As 2 sugestões funcionaram perfeitamente. Vou aproveitar as 2 tb para outras funções. Muito Obrigado pela atenção!!!

Comment: Tentei ticar as 2 respostas, mas só aceita 1. Rray agradeço por dedicar seu tempo e conhecimento. Boa Sorte a todos.

Comment: @Geo o importante é sempre continuar a aprender, boa sorte. A comunidade ta aqui sempre pra te ajudar a crescer.

Answer (score 3):

Como o objetivo é comparar o valor de `letra` com o item atual do array `str(i)`.

Uma forma de fazer isso com php é criar um gabarito atra´ves de um array onde as chaves são as letras(A-Z) e os valores são de 1-26 quem realizada essa tarefa é `array_merge()` que recebe dois argumentos o primeiros são as chaves do novo array e o segundo os valores. Depois disso basta verificar se existe o indice `$letra` em `$str` caso positivo escreve `novidade-` seguido do valor.

```
$arr = array('01A', '01B', '01C', '01Z');
$titulo = 'novidade';
$str =  array_combine(range('A', 'Z'), range(1,26));


foreach($arr as $v){
    $letra = substr($v, -1, 1);
    if(isset($str[$letra])){
        echo 'novidade-'.$str[$letra] .'<br>';
    }   
}
```

Saida:

```
novidade-1
novidade-2
novidade-3
novidade-26
```

Comment: rray, agradeço, informo mais detalhes: O array contém só letras (alfabeto completo de A a Z). Os COD são nnA (2 nºs e 1 letra). A função compara a letra do COD e incrementa no título o '-1' se for letra A; '-2' se for letra B assim por diante. Espero ter esclarecido, qq dúvida post. Obrigado.

Comment: Esqueci de informar o mais importante. Antes da função tem; letra=right(cod,1) aqui é separada a letra do cod para a função comparar. desculpe a falha.

Comment: @Geo então vc compara apenas se as letras são iguais e aí faz o incremento?

Comment: isto mesmo. por exemplo COD=23B o titulo fica = novidade-2

Comment: @Geo editei a resposta veja se agora está correta.